Someone in white gloves is seen stealing a child, and then raises it as their own
Can you please identify this movie.
This film is pre-2010. 
The premise is that someone in white gloves steals a child from a crib, and the parents get really depressed. The movie follows the kid and his single mom. The kid then finds out that he was stolen as an infant, and that his high school teacher is in fact his birth mother. 
At the end of the movie they are in a dark alley way and he is crying, trying to hug her, but her husband beats the kid up thinking he's some kind of creep. 
He explains everything and they live happily ever after. 

Do you honestly mean to say that a film from 2010 is "old" or am I misunderstanding your "five years" statement?

Sounds like There Was a Little Boy from 1993 with Cybill Shepherd.

Wealthy Gregg and his wife, English teacher Julie, were happy parents until their little boy Robby was stolen while she took a bath. Their lives have taken off again, but they keep hoping and feeling guilty. Fifteen years later, when Julie is pregnant again, the high school principal appeals to her educational idealism to take under her wing Jesse, a boy who is gifted as a mechanic and artist, but can barely be convinced to keep in school by his single devoted and devout mother Esperanza, who is sick and such a bad provider he has to steal.

Jesse turns out to be her kidnapped son. It seems you remembered some of the details wrong though (there are no white gloves and the confrontation in the end between the boy and his mom and dad takes place in the house). The entire movie is currently available on Youtube.
